# Tokeniser to parse UK postcode

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I need to create a custom analyzer for Elasticsearch 1.7 to support a postcode district (first part of a postcode) search where the first two alphabetic characters in the search term find only postcodes that begin with that exact term.

In other words, that a search term of "G" finds:

```
G1
G23
```

but not

```
GL2
GL4
```

And a search term of "GL" produces

```
GL2
GL4
```

etc.

I'm working with the idea of a pattern tokenizer with regex that groups the alphabetic and numeric components of the first part of the postcode. According to the [Elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html), "the regular expression should match the token separators, not the tokens themselves". However, I'm not clear what that would look like in the regex output.

The analyzer I have come up with so far looks like this:

```
{
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocompletePostcodeDistrict": {
          "tokenizer": "postcodeTokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "postcodeTokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "\b([a-z]{1,2})(\\d[a-z])|([a-z]{1,2})(\\d{1,2})\b",
          "lowercase": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I ran the following postcode districts through the regular expression and the results are below.

```
G1
1: <blank>
2: <blank>
3:G
4:1

GL2
1: <blank>
2: <blank>
3:GL
4:2

G12
1: <blank>
2: <blank>
3:G
4:12

WC1V
1: WC
2: 1V
3: <blank>
4: <blank>
```

I haven't found a way of suppressing the blank groups. However, the expression appears to parse the postcode districts in a way that create groups that match the tokens I think the tokeniser needs to create. However the analyser doesn't have the desired search behaviour.

Can anyone lend a hand, please?

**Update**

A first fix is to change the characters in the regex from [A-Z] to [a-z] to reflect the fact that all the filtering is lower case (fixed above). But it still doesn't achieve desired search behaviour.

Comment: Maybe you need to avoid using capturing groups and just use `"[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}"`?

Comment: But then the regex just matches the whole expression (provided it is a valid postcode district). Somehow I think it needs to show the analyser how to tokenize the postcode district so that the search works as desired.

Comment: for the above probably it would be  simpler to use a [word_delimiter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) filter instead of pattern_tokenizer.